# How to generate a GET request from my jsp with a given "value"

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am new to Web Development.

I am trying to develop a web application using Spring 3. I have my "Hello World" code setup done and is working fine.

Now , in my controller I understand that I can create a Handling method with  @RequestMapping annotation that would handle HTTP requests.

My question is, how do I generate a  new request (say on click of a specific button)  from my jsp page,so that it gets handled by a new method specific to that request in my controller.

One way I think I can do is submit a form like:

```
<form action="hi">
```

and handle that form with RequestMapping as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hi", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Is there any other way to map specific requests from jsp page to specific methods in my controller?

Comment: You typically do that by having a link in the page, whose href contains the URL to which the controller method is mapped to: `<a href="hi">Click here to say hi</a>`. I suggest you try building a completely static web site to learn these basics before jumping into Spring MVC.

Comment: Ok so when I click on the link you mentioned, it will be mapped to a controller method with 

@RequestMapping(value = "/hi", method = RequestMethod.GET)
?

Comment: Really, learn the basics of HTTP and HTML. Yes, a hyperlink, when clicked, sends a GET request to the URL contained in its `href` attribute. In this case, the URL is a relative one. So if the address displayed in the address bar of the browser is `http://foo.com/bar/baz`, it will send a GET request to `http://foo.com/bar/hi`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JBNizet .. I am in a situation where I have to learn everything on the go :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other way is to use links:

```
<a href="YOUR_APPLICATION_URL">Method invocation</a>
```